# Is "he registered in my mind" a common idiom?

Tags: idioms, idiom-requests

Example sentence:

> **He registered in my mind.** He was John Anderson.

(Meaning that I knew who the person was.)

Is this a common idiom? If not, what's the closest alternative?

Comment: As answers have already said, it's not an idiom. When you say "you know who the person is", what do you mean? Do you mean that you _recognised_ him (remember seeing him before, and remembered his name), that you have _heard of him_ (but not necessarily seen him, before), or that you have _met_ him before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not an idiom per se. But use it; why not? Some of the definitions for *register* supports such usage.

Plus, I'd rephrase it to: "**It** registered in my mind; he was John Anderson."

Using "in my mind" is actually unnecessary if you are already using "registered", but it's fine to have some redundancy.

***Register*** -- [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/register)

> (verb) 3.2 *usually with negative* Notice or become aware of.
>   ‘he hadn't even registered her presence’
>
> 3.3 *no object, usually with negative* Make an impression on a person's mind.
>   ‘My mind registers that there's a guy pulling me down.’

Answer (score 1):

This is not a common idiom. The more common form would be, "he came to mind."

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard or read a phrase like the one you wrote.
I'd rather say

> He sticked in my memory

or

> He got stuck in my mind

for a more negative nuance...